# Eclipse complains about ambiguity while trying to call a constructor using a WritableList

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I have a class with some constructors like this:

```
public MyClass(Control caller, WritableList elements, String pattern) {
    this(caller, elements, pattern, new LabelProvider());
}

public MyClass(Control caller, WritableList elements, String pattern, ILabelProvider labelProvider) {
    super(caller.getShell(), labelProvider);
    // ...
}

public MyClass(Control caller, Collection<String> elements, String pattern) {
    super(caller.getShell(), new LabelProvider());
    // ...
}
```

If I try to create an instance of it using this:

```
new MyClass(getControl(), getWritableList(), "test");
```

or this:

```
new MyClass(getControl(), (WritableList) getWritableList(), "test");
```

Eclipse is complaining that the constructor is ambiguous. If I do this however:

```
new MyClass(getControl(), (Collection<SomeType>) getWritableList(), "test");
```

everything is fine. I was wondering what could be the problem? I'm using `org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.list.WritableList` which comes with the RCP framework.

**Edit:**

I thought that `WritableList` extending the `Collection` interface could be the error but I created some test classes and it turned out that it is not the case:

```
public class Main {
    /**
     * Main.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass obj = new TestClass(getTypeAInstance(), "asd");
    }

    public static SomeTypeA getTypeAInstance() {
        return new SomeTypeA();
    }

    public static interface SomeInterface<T> {

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static interface SomeInterfaceExtensionWithoutTypeParam extends SomeInterface {

    }

    public static interface SomeInterfaceExtensionWithTypeParam<T> extends SomeInterface<T> {

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static interface SomeIntermediateInterface extends SomeInterfaceExtensionWithoutTypeParam, SomeInterfaceExtensionWithTypeParam {

    }

    public static class SomeTypeA implements SomeIntermediateInterface {

    }

    public static class TestClass {
        public TestClass(SomeInterface<String> i, String s) {
        }

        public TestClass(SomeTypeA a, String s) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `WritableList` implements the `Collections` interface. This is probably what is causing your error.

Comment: What version of Java and Eclipse do you use? Can you also provide signatures of `getControl` and `getWritableList` methods? I've tested the above code in Eclipse Juno on Java 7 (on Windows) and everything works well.

Comment: Funny - using your new sample, I get the same error when compiling from the command line using Java 1.6.0_25, but when I use the same JVM in Eclipse it doesn't complain at all

Comment: I'm using 1.6.25 too. Pretty weird!

Comment: For what it's worth, Eclipse uses its own incremental Java compiler, so using javac from the command line might yield different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was with Eclipse's own Java compiler.